# Tools for Computer Repair

Tags: maintenance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do you put in your computer repair toolkit?](https://superuser.com/questions/17333/what-do-you-put-in-your-computer-repair-toolkit)

Sir,

I have an urgent requirement to demand the list of the following for the purpose
of repairing and maintenance of Computer and its common peripherals. This requirement 
is to set up a computer maintenance lab. Kindly post me the list of the following.

(1) General purpose tools for computer repairing
(2) Technical Name of Tool kit to be used for the same purpose
(3) Instruments used for computer maintenance and repairs
(4) Software (other than anti-virus) used for computer maintenance
(5) Special tools/toolkit for computer networking
(6) Any other special technical advise for tools/instrument/equipment

Thanks !

P N Baliya

Comment: Duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/17333/what-do-you-put-in-your-computer-repair-toolkit and http://superuser.com/questions/2/free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows

Comment: It's also six questions!

Answer (score 0):

*(1) General purpose tools for computer repairing

(2) Technical Name of Tool kit to be used for the same purpose

(3) Instruments used for computer maintenance and repairs*

[what-do-you-put-in-your-computer-repair-toolkit](https://superuser.com/questions/17333/what-do-you-put-in-your-computer-repair-toolkit)

(4) Software (other than anti-virus) used for computer maintenance

[free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows](https://superuser.com/questions/2/free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows)
[user-safe-malware-removal-tools](https://superuser.com/questions/5478/user-safe-malware-removal-tools)

(5) Special tools/toolkit for computer networking
(6) Any other special technical advise for tools/instrument/equipment

Comment: i really wanna add *"hire a technician who knows how to use the tools"* after #6, but it might be taken as smartassery.

Comment: @~quack - yep :-))